# Convert os.Signal to string to be able to print it in afile

Tags: linux, go

I need to Convert the os.signal type to string to be able to save it in a file.

```
err := ioutil.WriteFile("out", sig, 0644)
```

I get error like this:

```
./signals.go:37: cannot use sig (type os.Signal) as type []byte in argument to ioutil.WriteFile
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do

```
err := ioutil.WriteFile("out", []byte(sig.String()), 0644)
```